# uicc toolkit install parameter return 6A80

Tags: nfc, toolkit, apdu

I have problem with the uicc toolkit install params.. Long tries, but no success..

Have simple uicc toolkit code.. Can't understand where is my error.. Here is my install parameter APDU.. Become always 6A80..

```
    80 E6 0C 00 => CLA INS P1(Selectable) P2 
    41 => TOTAL DATA LEN
    //AID's
    0A 51 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 
    0B 51 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 
    0B 51 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 

    01 00 => Privileges

    => Begin of install pararms
    1A => LEN INSTALL PARAMS
    EF 08 => System specific param Tag + Len
    C7 02 00 00 C8 02 00 00 => volatile and nonvolatile mem quota
    C9 00 => Application specific params (Tag + Len)
    EA 0C
    80 UICC Toolkit Application specific parameters field 
    00 => prio level
    00 => max timer allowed
    10 => max text length
    01 => max menu entry
    00 => pos of the mneu entry
    00 => identifier of the menu entry
    02 => max number of channels
    01 => len of msl
    00 => msl
    00 => len of tar values
    00 => max number of this appl. instances
    => End of install pararms

    00 => Install Token Len
    00 => LE
```

My goal is a contactless + uicc STK applet. But I even cannot install a simple uicc toolkit applet..

Hope, anybody has an idea..

Best regards..

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to standard specification from ETSI [here](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102200_102299/102226/09.02.00_60/ts_102226v090200p.pdf).

The [SIM Alliance](http://www.simalliance.org/) also has good resource for this: [Stepping Stones R7](http://www.simalliance.org/en?t=/documentManager/sfdoc.file.detail&ParentID=1188397757821&fileID=1236162278836&active=SFDOC) document. For install parameter see section 21.2.3 on (U)SAT. You need to register (free) before you can download.

Some remarks on your install command:

- Instance AID shall consist of 16 bytes, and having TAR at byte 13-15.
- Sequence of volatile and non-volatile must not be reversed
- UICC toolkit parameter shall come first, then the applet specific parameter
- Priority level shall not use 0x00 value since it is reserved
- No need LE byte since length of token is already 0

Hence, the install APDU shall look similar to this (need to re-calculate length denotes by LL)

```
80 E6 0C 00              -- CLA INS P1(Selectable) P2 
LL                       -- TOTAL DATA LEN 
//AID's
0A 51 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 
0B 51 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 
10 51 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 XX <3_bytes_TAR> XX 

01 00                   -- Privileges
1B                      -- LEN INSTALL PARAMS
    EF 08               -- System parameters
        C8 02 00 00     -- non volatile memory first
        C7 02 00 00     -- volatile memory
    EA LL               -- UICC system specific param first, tag C9 after this
        80 LL           -- UICC Toolkit Application specific parameters tag+length 
            FF          -- prio level (lowest priority)
            00          -- max timer allowed
            10          -- max text length
            01          -- max menu entry
            00          -- pos of the menu entry
            00          -- identifier of the menu entry
            02          -- max number of BIP channels
            01          -- len of msl
            00          -- msl
            00          -- len of tar values
            01          -- max number of this appl. instances
    C9 00               -- Application specific params
00                      -- Install Token length
```

Comment: Could you please add the Contactless Protocol Parameters (tag B0) to your install APDU?

Comment: I haven't used the parameter yet. You can refer to ETSI 102.226 v11 section 8.2.1.3.2.8. Additionally, you can also refer to Global Platform 2.2 Amnd C v1.1.1 and SIM Alliance's NFC Stepping Stones v1.0.0